# How to use /dev/(u)random

Tags: kernel, bash

How can I use `/dev/(u)random` on Ubuntu or any *nix sistems?

I tried this but it says permission denied.
Note : I also tried as root.

```
/dev/(u)random
sudo /dev/(u)random
sudo -s; /dev/(u)random
```

Comment: Please notice that these commands should be used only, when you really need high quality random data, typically in order to create good passwords. Otherwise there are more light-weight alternatives, for example the shell environment 'variable' `RANDOM` to create random positive integer numbers: `echo $RANDOM`, and the program `shuf` to generate random permutations, for example play in random order from a playlist.

Comment: you got the error because you are trying to execute it rather than read it.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It's a file like device, so you can do things like cat it or copy from it. For instance:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=~/urandom_test count=4 bs=1024
```

Creates a file containing 4K of random bytes.

```
cat /dev/urandom > ~/urandom_test2
```

Will continue to write random bytes to that file until you hit Ctrl-C. Don't do this on a low performing system...

```
head -30 /dev/urandom > ~/urandom_test3
```

Will write 30 lines of random bytes

Comment: Feel free to upvote then!

Comment: I would if my rep > 15

Comment: Note : Don't do cat /dev/urandom > ~/urandom_test2 on low-performance systems -> that freezes the system

Comment: Ah, true. I'll change my second example.

Comment: The 30 lines will be of random lenght too, I guess? (It's not really lines of random bytes)

Comment: Well.. that really depends on your definition of a line. My definition is `bytes terminated by a \n`. What's yours? `head -30 /dev/urandom` will give you 30 lines of random bytes. The length of those lines will certainly be random. Try running `wc -l` on your output file if you aren't convinced.

Comment: Note that `/dev/urandom` is limited to 32 MiB per `read()` and `dd` will not retry to read more once `/dev/urandom` yields those 32 MiB, so you have to call `dd` with `iflag=fullblock`. See [dd is producing a 32 MB random file instead of 1 GB](https://superuser.com/q/1388082/418028)

Answer (score 27):

### Get random bytes

If you need a certain number of random bytes, read that number of bytes from `/dev/urandom`.
It is a "special file" that is made to be like a file to read random numbers from.

Using `cat` to read from `/dev/urandom` is a bad idea, because it will try to read `/dev/urandom` to the end - but it does not end.

You can use `head`. But take care to read by byte, not by line - because lines would be randomly separated by random newline bytes.

So, to read 30 random bytes into a file `random.bytes`, use:

```
head -c 30 /dev/urandom > random.bytes
```

You can read from it as a normal user.

### Leave alone /dev/random

Normally, you want to use `/dev/urandom`, not `/dev/random`.

The problem is that `/dev/random` is hard to use in the right way - and easy to use in a wrong way. Using it wrong works at first, but creates strange - even random - performance problems later. Sometimes.

When you use `/dev/urandom`, it makes use of `/dev/random` internally, taking care of the tricky parts.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to just read it with recognized numbers you can do

```
od -d /dev/random
```

Comment: I think `/dev/urandom` is preferable

Answer (score 6):

I personally use this for generating tokens:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom  count=1 bs=128 | sha512sum
```